# IE8 won't display PNG

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, png

## Problem

I have an image in PNG that displays properly on my website on **chrome** and **firefox**, but **not on IE8**. It displays the dreadfull *empty square with a red **X***.

## Question

Why this `.PNG` image doesn't work on IE8?

## Code

```
<asp:Image ID="IMG_Logo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo.png" height="150px"/>
```

## Notes

- IE8 displays other images (in other websites), so my browser is not the problem (no AD-BLOCK, no option ticked off, etc).
- Image.png is displayed on others web pages, so the image itself is fine.
- Logo.png is **2800px by 800px** shrinked to **150px height** by asp.net.
- I'm working on **Visual Web Developper Express 2010**, with **IIS 7.5 express**.
  Chrome gives and IE8 give the exact same HTML:

Trying to follow the image path :

`http://*MyWebSite*/Images/Logo.png`

It works fine in Chrome/Firefox again, but does a `Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found` on IE8.

Converting the `.png`(300ko) into `.jpeg`(250ko) (in RGB format) fixes the problem. But the question remains :

#### Why does the JPEG file works fine while the PNG file breaks in IE8?

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML? What is the actual generated image URL? Does it refer to a valid URL? Try to use Fiddler to capture the actual requests made from the browser and the results. You may find that the resulting URL is wrong or you get an access denied error for the image

Comment: See my update 1, the resulting URL is fine, I get an error 404.0 not found on IE8..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos See Update2, I found a workaround (converting the image from .png to .jpeg. But I'm still wondering as to why IE8 breaks when the image is .png, but works when it is .jpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Just came across exactly the same thing. The issue was specific to .png files in IE8. It seems there are different kinds of .png files. I resolved the issue by editing the problem .png in GIMP and then exporting it as a .png again, using the GIMP defaults for:

- Save background color
- Save resolution
- Save creation time
- Save color values from transparent pixels

I'm afraid I don't know specifically what was different between the original .png file and the new one I saved (I'm not a designer or a techie). I just know that the first one didn't work, whereas the second one did. Hope this helps someone anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue and it was related to the type of PNG file. Simply loading the PNG in GIMP and re-exporting it as PNG solved the issue.

I suspect it was due to some transparency or bit depth setting of the PDF that IE8 could not render.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be due to a conflict with quick-time:

[.PNG's breaking in IE 7 and 8, red x white border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625906/pngs-breaking-in-ie-7-and-8-red-x-white-border)

The link above says to: Right click the PNG and make sure its associated with IE explorer and not quick time or another program.

Comment: I am able to see PNG images from other websites with IE8. So it can't be related to what the extention is associated to. And in any case, we do not have QuickTime installed, so it can't be that.